# How to Implement Pending Attachments with Uploadset?

Tags: sapui5

There aren't good, complete guides published that help users ramp up to speed on how to implement pending attachments with the more recent UploadSet control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Improvements are most welcome.

Here is the Full implementation for Pending Upload with additional functionalities like:

- Load Attachments,
- CheckBox to (de)select all files for useor convenience,
- Download, and
- Busy Indicator while Uploading/Downloading.

Tip: Avoid the other control called `UploadCollection`, there are too many bugs and there were too many hours lost trying to figure out alternatives. `UploadSet` is your bug-free shiny, best friend.

How it Looks: *Alignment of checkbox and modification of control's visuals was done through custom CSS (referenced in this answer)

[image: hi]

Pre-requisites:

- Scaffold `sap/m/MessageBox` as `MessageBox` and `sap/m/MessageToast` as `MessageToast`
- `UploadSet`'s namespace: `xmlns:up="sap.m.upload"`
- define `var that` = `this` either globally or in each function `that` is used in

1. View:

   ```
   <up:UploadSet id="attachmentUpl" instantUpload="false" maxFileSize="2" noDataDescription="" noDataText="" selectionChanged="onSelectionChangeAttachment"
   uploadCompleted="onUploadCompleted" uploadUrl="/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z9NRS_CONFIG_SRV/Z9NRS_REQ_ATTACHSet" visible="true">
       <up:toolbar>
           <OverflowToolbar>
               <CheckBox id="checkbox" select="onSelectAllAttachments" visible="false" />
               <ToolbarSpacer/>
               <Button id="upload" enabled="true" text="Upload" press="onStartUpload" type="Transparent" visible="true" />
               <Button id="remove" enabled="false" icon="sap-icon://delete" press="onRemove" type="Transparent" visible="true" />
               <Button id="download" enabled="false" icon="sap-icon://download" press="onDownload" type="Transparent" visible="true" />
           </OverflowToolbar>
       </up:toolbar>
   </up:UploadSet>
   ```
2. Controller:

Within `onInit`:

```js
var oAttachmentUpl= this.byId('attachmentUpl').getDefaultFileUploader();
oAttachmentUpl.setIcon("sap-icon://add").setIconOnly(true);
oAttachmentUpl.setMultiple(true); //lets user select more than 1file at a time in their FileExplorer
```

Load Attachments:

```js
loadAttachments:function(){
      var sPath= "/Z9NRS_REQ_ATTACHSet?$filter=(ZNRS_REQUEST eq '"+sRequestId+"')";
      var oAttachmentUpl= this.byId("attachmentUpl");
      oAttachmentUpl.getList().setMode("MultiSelect");
      this.getView().getModel().read(sPath,{
        success:function(oData){
            var oAttachmentsModel= new JSONModel(oData);
            oAttachmentUpl.setModel(oAttachmentsModel).bindAggregation("items", "/results", new sap.m.upload.UploadSetItem({
                fileName: "{FILE_NAME}", mediaType: "{MIME_TYPE}", visibleEdit:false, visibleRemove:false,
                url: "/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z9NRS_CONFIG_SRV/Z9NRS_REQ_ATTACHSet(ZNRS_REQUEST='" + "{OBJECT_ID}" + "',FILE_NAME='" + "{FILE_NAME}" + "')/$value"
            }));
            if(oAttachmentUpl.getItems().length>0){
                that.byId('checkbox').setVisible(true);
            }
        },
        error:function(oError){that.parseErrorMsg()}
    });
}
```

Everything else:

```js
onSelectAllAttachments: function(oEvent) {
    var aUploadedItems = this.byId("attachmentUpl").getItems(),
      bSelected = oEvent.getSource().getSelected();
    if (bSelected) { //if CheckBox is selected
      aUploadedItems.forEach(oItem => oItem.getListItem().setSelected(true));
      this.byId('download').setEnabled(true);
    } else {
      aUploadedItems.forEach(oItem => oItem.getListItem().setSelected(false));
      this.byId('remove').setEnabled(false);
      this.byId('download').setEnabled(false);
    }
  },
  onSelectionChangeAttachment: function() {
    if (this.byId("attachmentUpl").getList().getSelectedItems().length > 0) { //if user selects 1 or more uploaded item
      this.byId("remove").setEnabled(true);
      this.byId("download").setEnabled(true);
    } else {
      this.byId("remove").setEnabled(false);
      this.byId("download").setEnabled(false);
    }
  },
  onRemove: function(oEvent) {
    var oAttachmentUpl = this.byId("attachmentUpl");
    oAttachmentUpl.setBusy(true);
    oAttachmentUpl.getItems().forEach(oItem => {
      if (oItem.getListItem().getSelected()) {
        var sPath = oItem.getProperty("url").split("SRV")[1]; //eg /Z9NRS_REQ_ATTACHSet
        this.getView().getModel().remove(sPath, {
          success: function() {
            oAttachmentUpl.removeItem(oItem); //remove from displayed list
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            that.parseErrorMsg();
          }
        });
      }
    });
    oEvent.getSource().setEnabled(false);
    this.byId("download").setEnabled(false);

    if (oAttachmentUpl.getItems().length > 0) {
      this.byId('checkbox').setVisible(true);
    } else {
      this.byId('checkbox').setVisible(false);
    }
    oAttachmentUpl.setBusy(false);
  },
  onDownload: function(oEvent) {
    var oAttachmentUpl = this.byId("attachmentUpl");
    oAttachmentUpl.setBusy(true);
    oAttachmentUpl.getItems().forEach(oItem => {
      if (oItem.getListItem().getSelected()) {
        oItem.download(true);
        oItem.getListItem().setSelected(false);
      }
    });
    oAttachmentUpl.setBusy(false);
    oEvent.getSource().setEnabled(false);
  },
  onStartUpload: function() {
    var oAttachmentUpl = this.byId("attachmentUpl");
    var aIncompleteItems = oAttachmentUpl.getIncompleteItems();
    this.iIncompleteItems = aIncompleteItems.length; //used to turn off busy indicator upon completion of all pending uploads
    if (this.iIncompleteItems !== 0) {
      oAttachmentUpl.setBusy(true);
      this.i = 0; //used to turn off busy indicator when all uploads complete
      for (var i = 0; i < this.iIncompleteItems; i++) {
        var sFileName = aIncompleteItems[i].getProperty("fileName");
        var oXCSRFToken = new sap.ui.core.Item({
          key: "X-CSRF-Token",
          text: this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().getSecurityToken()
        });
        var oSlug = new sap.ui.core.Item({
          key: "SLUG",
          text: this.sRequestId + "/" + sFileName
        });
        oAttachmentUpl.addHeaderField(oXCSRFToken).addHeaderField(oSlug).uploadItem(aIncompleteItems[i]);
        oAttachmentUpl.removeAllHeaderFields(); //at least slug header field must be reset after each upload
      }
    }
  },
  onUploadCompleted: function() {
    this.i += 1;
    if (this.i === this.iIncompleteItems) { //turn off busy indicator when all attachments have completed uploading
      this.byId('attachmentUpl').setBusy(false);
    }
  },
  parseErrorMsg: function(oError) { //parses oData error messages dependent on different return values
    var oMessage, sType;
    if (oError.response) { //for update
      sType = typeof oError.response;
      if (sType === "string" || sType === "object") oMessage = JSON.parse(oError.response.body).error.message.value;
      else return MessageBox.error("Unhandled server error:\n\n" + oError.response + "\n\nReport this issue to Admin for a future fix.");
    } else if (oError.responseText) { //for create
      sType = typeof oError.responseText;
      if (sType === "string" || sType === "object") oMessage = JSON.parse(oError.responseText).error.message.value;
      else return MessageBox.error("Unhandled server error:\n\n" + oError.responseText + "\n\nReport this issue to Admin for a future fix.");
    } else if (!oError) return MessageToast.show("Error message is undefined");
    MessageBox.error(oMessage);
  }
```

3. CSS:

```css
/*uploadSet: align toolbar checkbox with ListItems' checkboxes*/
.sapMIBar.sapMTB.sapMTBNewFlex.sapMTBInactive.sapMTBStandard.sapMTB-Transparent-CTX {
    padding-left: 2px;
}
/*uploadSet: reduce height of each uploadItem*/
.sapMLIB.sapMLIB-CTX.sapMLIBShowSeparator.sapMLIBTypeInactive.sapMLIBFocusable.sapMCLI.sapMUCItem {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
/*uploadSet: align uploadItem checkboxes to center*/
.sapMCb.sapMLIBSelectM {
    align-self: center !important;
}
/*uploadSet: remove rename icon from pending files*/
.sapMBtnBase.sapMBtn.sapMUCEditBtn.sapMUCFirstButton {
    display: none;
}
/*uploadSet: remove pending bar and text*/
.sapMFlexBox.sapMVBox.sapMFlexBoxJustifyStart.sapMFlexBoxAlignItemsStretch.sapMFlexBoxWrapNoWrap.sapMFlexBoxAlignContentStretch.sapMFlexBoxBGTransparent.sapMUSProgressBox {
    display: none;
}
/*uploadSet: center the x button for pending files*/
.sapMUCButtonContainer {
    align-self: center;
}
```

Simply press your `Upload` button (located in your UploadSet's toolbar) to upload all pending attachments.

***All items needing to be customized in order to get your implementation working***:

- `sPath` for your oData call in the `loadAttachments` function as well as pretty much all parameters in your UploadSetItem
- `uploadUrl` property of your `UploadSet` control
- `sPath` for your oData call in the `onRemove` function
- SLUG header `text` value in your `onStartUpload` function

Functionalities NOT included:

- Refresh UploadSet's list of items after upload completion

Comment: How have you defined oDataModel used for getting token ?

Comment: SecurityToken is retrieved from ODataModel, which was added via DataSource in manifest.json

Answer (score 2):

Additional functionality:

- Unsupported File Type, File Size Exceeded, Multi-File Progress (And Upload Fail:

View: add following properties to your UploadSet, example below:

```html
beforeUploadStarts="onBeforeUploadStarts" //this will update multi-file upload progress through MessageToast and MessageBox prompts
fileTypes="pdf,doc,docx,docm,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,jpg,jpeg,png"
fileTypeMismatch="onFileTypeMismatch"
maxFileSize="2"
fileSizeExceeded="onFileSizeExceeded"
```

Controller:

```js
onBeforeUploadStarts: function(oEvent) { //track file upload progress
    var oUploadSet = oEvent.getSource(),
      iOldList = oUploadSet.getIncompleteItems().length;
    setTimeout(() => this.checkFileUploadFailed(oUploadSet, iOldList), 10000); // recursive func that checks status of itemslist
  },
checkFileUploadFailed: function(oUploadSet, iOldList) {
  if (iOldList !== 0) {
    var iNewList = oUploadSet.getIncompleteItems().length;
    if (iNewList === iOldList) {
      MessageToast.show("File upload(s) pending");
      if (!this.iPendingFilesCounter) this.iPendingFilesCounter = 0;
      this.iPendingFilesCounter += 1;
      if (this.iPendingFilesCounter === 3) {
        MessageBox.error("File uploads taking longer than expected.");
        oUploadSet.setBusy(false);
      }
      var iOldList = iNewList;
      setTimeout(() => this.checkFileUploadFailed(oUploadSet, iOldList), 10000);
    }
  }
},
  onFileTypeMismatch: function(oEvent) {
    var oItem = oEvent.getParameter("item");
    this.byId("attachmentUpl").removeIncompleteItem(oItem); //remove pending item user tried to add
    new sap.m.MessageToast.show(oItem.getProperty("fileName").split(".")[1] + " file type is not supported"); //show message toast with the specific fileType that isn't supported
  }
onFileSizeExceeded: function(oEvent) {
  var oAttachmentUpl = this.byId("attachmentUpl"),
    oItem = oEvent.getParameter("item");
  oAttachmentUpl.removeIncompleteItem(oItem); //remove pending item user tried to add
  new sap.m.MessageToast.show("Maximum file size of " + oAttachmentUpl.getMaxFileSize() + " MB exceeded"); //show message toast with the max file size supported
}
```